# is it possible to get all pods from a list of namescapes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a lot of namespaces and I want to get all pods from a sub-list of namespaces.

For getting all the pods from all namespace the command is:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

To get all pods from a spesific namespace the command is:

```
kubectl get pods -n namespace-name
```

However I can't find a way to get all pods from a list of namespaces, something like:

```
kubectl get pods -n namespace-name1, namespace-name2, namespace-name3
```

what is the right command for that?

Answer (score 2):

kubectl does not support this. You can use egrep to filter the list of all pods by namespaces:

```
kubectl get pods -A | egrep '^(namespace-name1|namespace-name2|namespace-name3)'
```

Because `kubectl` prints the namespace at the beginning of the line, it greps for a line start `^` followed by one of the namespace names.

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work, I used ```--all-namespaces``` and the filtered by namespace

Comment: `-A` is the same as `--all-namespaces`. Do you still get pods from all namespaces or nothing at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the subset of namespaces:

Either:

```bash
for NAMESPACE in "namespace-1" "namespace-2"
do
  kubectl get pods \
  --namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
  --output=name
done
```

Or:

```bash
NAMESPACE=$(
  "namespace-1"
  "namespace-2"
)
for NAMESPACE in "${NAMESPACES[@]}"
do
  kubectl get pods \
  --namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
  --output=name
done
```